# JPA Remove doesn't work at all

Tags: java, jpa

Good day,

I've the following Entity Class that I've used for my normal inserting and updating using (persist and merge).

In my SessionBean I managed to have a DataTable that will give me a selected item as an entity which is very basic as below:

```
 //Remove Selected row Loaner info
public String deleteLoanerInfo() throws RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, SystemException, NotSupportedException{

   Loaner current = (Loaner) getItems().getRowData();
    System.out.println("Current: " + current );

        utx.begin();
        Loaner s = emf.createEntityManager().find(Loaner.class, current.getLoanerId());
        System.out.println("S: "+ s);
        emf.createEntityManager().remove(emf.createEntityManager().merge(s));
        utx.commit();


    //Refresh Datatable
    recreatePagination();
    recreateModel();
    return "";
}
```

But once I try to remove this entity using the remove() I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must be managed to call remove: loan.system.entities.Loaner[ loanerId=1 ], try merging the detached and try the remove again.
```

I really appreciate your kind assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally managed to get it sorted!!

I tried to call flush() to synch data removal with DB and I got :

```
Cannot call methods requiring a transaction if the entity manager has not been joined to the current transaction
```

and after some invistegation I found that this was a bug reported to Eclipse as explained in the following link:
[Bug 404294 - EclipseLink incorrectly uses active transactions despite not being joined to them](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404294)

The final and tested code after all is the following:

```
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Loaner current = (Loaner) getItems().getRowData();

        utx.begin();
        Loaner s = em.find(Loaner.class, current.getLoanerId());
        Loaner tmp = em.merge(s);
        em.remove(tmp);
        em.joinTransaction(); // <-- This is the fix
        em.flush(); // <-- after flushing the state of persistent entities is synchronized to the database
        utx.commit();
```

So thank you guys for such help

Answer (score 4):

Because you are calling `find` and `remove` on two different `EntityManager` instances.

You need to do something like this instead

```
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  utx.begin();
  Loaner s = em.find(Loaner.class, current.getLoanerId());
  System.out.println("S: "+ s);
  em.remove(s);
  utx.commit();
```

Comment: No need to merge here. If you do not need the state of the entity, EntityManager#getRefrence is sufficient.

Comment: I applied this solution but still the data is not erased from DB... weird!!